# render same dataRow too much every time

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Items re-render multiple times Whenever new Items are added to data prop array. So how can I avoid this useless re-rendering of items.

I am using

react-native 0.59.0

react 16.8.3

This is what I get when I log, Items in it's render method

renderItem 0

renderItem 1

renderItem 2

renderItem 3

// from here render again
renderItem 0

renderItem 1

renderItem 2

renderItem 3

renderItem 4

renderItem 5

renderItem 6

renderItem 7

```
//gettingData and displaying component

let offset = this.props.fetchedData.length;

//function to fetch data from server
getData() {
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        limit: 20,
        offset,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => (response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          if (responseJson.status) {
               this.props.fetchedDataChange(responseJson.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
        }));
}

//renderItem function for flatlist
renderItem({ item }) {
  return (
     <View>
       <Text>
          {item.name}
       </Text>
     </View>
  );
}

render() {
   return (
   <View>
      <FlatList
         data={this.props.fetchedData}
         renderItem={{ item } => this.renderItem({ item })}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         extraData={this.props}
         initialNumToRender={20}
         maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
         onEndReached={() => this.getData()}
         onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      />
   </View>
);
}

const mapStateToDispatchProps = dispatch => ({
 fetchedDataChange: value => dispatch(fetchedDataChange(value)
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  fetchedData: state.fetchedDataReducer.fetchedData
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(gettingData);



//fetchedData reducer component

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   fetchedData: [],
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHED_DATA_CHANGED:
      return {
           ...state,
           fetchedData: [...state.fetchedData, ...action.payload]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: are you using redux?

Comment: can you please add your code!

Comment: yes, I am using redux,

Comment: I have added the code, pleae check it @ParasKorat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data prop is getting updated from state variable everytime state changes re-rendering will occur.

Comment: yes, data prop is getting updated by adding new items. Is there any way I can stop re-rendering all the items. I have updated the question with example code, will you please check that

Comment: Every single time your props will change re-rendering will occur. For more about re-rendering read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: So, there will be no way to add items to data prop without reloading whole items in FlatList??

Comment: No. This is for sure that If props changes re-rendering will happen.

Comment: Thank you @avani kothari

Comment: happy to help :) please give tick to my answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: I have checked it with static data too. But it still re-rendering items, is this is a bug in the latest version (0.59.2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) which implements a shallow comparison to decide if rerender is needed. You can also achieve this by implementing [shouldComponentUpdate() on React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

There is already an [example in FlatList's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) that demonstrate how you can use PureComponent to render your list, just scroll down abit and look for the "more complex example" :)

If you prefer to use a `Functional Component` instead of a `Class Component`, checkout [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), which is similar to `React.PureComponent` but for `Functional Components`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using PureComponent. But when ever new items added to  data prop array, state changes and re-renders whole FlatList items, I want to render only the new items added to the data prop